# Converting values in an array to their pairs using a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

So I have a python dictionary with about 40 entries where the keys and the values are both numbers. I have a numpy array that is a very long list of numbers, where each number is one of the keys in the dictionary.

I want to be able to create a new array except each number is replaced with its corresponding value using the dictionary but I am stuck with what is the best way. I realize that a simple loop will do the trick, but I was really wondering if there is any faster way to do this or if there are any functions that could help?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? You haven't even shared some example input and output. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic], [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`np.vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) to apply a custom mapping function where each key in the `arr` will be replaced by the corresponding value in the `dictionary`.

*You can use this:*

```
import numpy as np

d = {1:10, 2:20, 3:30, 4:50}
arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])

result = np.vectorize(lambda k: d[k])(arr)
```

*Output:*

```
>>> print(result)
[10 20 30 50]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to loop over your first array, then lookup the corresponding value out of your dictionary.

```
>>> data = [1, 5, 8]
>>> mapping = {1: 6, 5:0, 8: 3}
>>> [mapping[i] for i in data]
[6, 0, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array = [1, 2, 3]
dictionary = {1: 10, 2: 20, 3:40}
list(map(lambda key: dictionary[key], array))
```

or

```
[*map(lambda key: dictionary[key], array)]
```

Comment: `[*map(lambda key: dictionary[key], array)]` Why? If you need a list, why not just use a list comprehension?